# References for this ARMA two step method estimation

Tags: time-series, references

I was doing some survey on ARMA parameters estimation methods. While on that, I found these lecture notes: http://www.phdeconomics.sssup.it/documents/Lesson12.pdf

There, the author describes a two step estimation procedure for an $ARMA(p, q)$ model. Given $p$ and $q$, basically the process is as follows:

- First it runs the regression $Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^p \pi_iY_{t-i} + \epsilon_t$ and calculates $\hat{\epsilon} = Y_t - \sum_{i=1}^p \hat\pi_iY_{t-i}$ using OLS.
- Then, it estimates the parameters regressing $Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^p \phi_iY_{t-i} + \sum_{i=1}^q \theta_i\hat\epsilon_{t-i}+ \epsilon_t$. Again, using OLS
- The results from the last step are the author's estimates; $\{\hat\phi_i\}_{i=1}^p, \{\hat\theta_i\}_{i=1}^q$.

I am not asking about the merits of the procedure per se, but a reference to a textbook or paper where this method is investigated/described. I haven't been able to find any of such by myself.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It might be easiest if you just contacted the author of the slides directly.

Comment: I am not an academic myself, but a practitioner. I don't know if it is considered polite for me to contact a professor for such a question.

Comment: Most professors will be delighted if someone actually reads their slides and has a short question. Just send him an email. (If you start asking lengthy questions or requesting detailed explanations, their reactions may differ.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will write him.

Comment: If you get an answer, please consider writing up an answer here. It may be helpful for future generations.

Comment: Will do it if I get it.

Comment: For the record, I sent the author an email a month ago and got no answer yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method dates back to J. Durbin (1960) “The fitting of time series
models” (Intl Statis. Review, 233-244) and was for example exploited in a model
selection context by Hannan and Kavaleris (1984) (Biometrika 71, 273-280).

Comment: Thank you! Accepted and upvoted.It is not exactly the same method, though, as it uses $k$ >> $p$ as the lag order in the first step. Yet it clearly answers my question asking for bibliography for clarification.